# string to DATETIME PARSING IN ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, datepicker

I have designed a html page. i took date from calender(datepicker) in 1 text box in string format(mm/dd/yyyy),hour as string in other text box and minute as string in another text box. how to parse them together in date time format in asp.net.

Comment: can you  explain more please is not clear what you want to achieve ?does my answer satisfy your need

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a datepicker, you can get the datetime object from the datepicker it self. Then use the AddHour and AddMinutes functions on the datetime object.

```
DateTime date = dateTimePicker.Value;
date.AddMinutes(Convert.ToInt32(textbox1MINUTES.Text));
date.AddHours(Convert.ToInt32(textbox2HOURS.Text));
```

To make your code more fail save you can use Int.TryParse for parsing the values of your textboxes.

Comment: +1 i think this is what OP is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
 CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

DateTime  result = DateTime.ParseExact(textbox1.Text+" "+ textbox2.Text +textbox3.Text, "mm/dd/yyyy HHmm", provider);
```

Comment: Your code isn't relevant with the question IMO..

Comment: your code too :( let's the OP decide

Answer (score 0):

if i understand correctly - you have `DatePicker` (`Calendar` control) in `asp.net` to take the `Date` value from `user`.

for getting the `Time` value from user you have two `TextBox` controls

1. one Textbox is for taking `Hours` value.
2. another `Textbox` is for taking `Minutes` value.

So when user Selects `Date` from `Calendar` Control and enters the `Hours` and `Minutes` using `Textbox` controls, you want to parse both the Date and Time (Hours and Minutes) as DateTime using ASP.NET.

Try This:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String strDate = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();
    String strHours = txtHour.Text;
    String strMinutes = txtMinutes.Text;
    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(strDate + " " + strHours+":"+strMinutes, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);    
}
```